# Laravel hasMany conundrum

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The `Comment` model has the following relationship set:

```
function replies(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Reply', 'comment_id', 'id')->whereNotNull('replies.status');
}
```

The `replies()` needs to return the replies even if the status is null for the currently logged in user and not for the others. The others should see only replies that have status set (unless they are the owners in which case it should show to them)

I am having a tough time adding this logic to it; any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can look at model booting scopes, in your case you need to add a global scope inside the `App\Reply` model class:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('guest_filter_for_comments', function (Builder $builder) {
        return $builder->when(\Auth::check() == false, function ($query) {
            return $query->whereNotNull('replies.status');
        });
    });
}
```

And when you want to disable the filter whenever needed, you can just use `Comment::replies()->withoutGlobalScopes()` to retrieve unfiltered results when not authenticated.

BTW, You can use the same logic to filter out the comments related to the user. When you call `Comment::all()` with doing this for the authenticated user, it will filter out the related comments automatically if you use a boot scope for your `Comment` class.

### References:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#global-scopes (Anonymous global scopes)
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses

Comment: Thanks Taha, am trying out your solution.. will update you on how it goes

Comment: You're welcome. This is a very useful method to filter authenticated/unauthenticated models. No need to do anything else in the business layer.